# VB 2010 - MS Access SQL. How to write Update Query: Table1.Column1 = Table1.Column1 + Table2.Column1 WHERE Table2.SomeColumn=Something

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

I am trying to make Update like this:

Table1.Column1 = Table1.Column1 + Table2.Column1 WHERE Table2.SomeColumn=Something. I need to make updates like this for 25 columns that have same names in Table1 and Table2 but please without INNER JOIN ON Table1.ColumnName = Table2.ColumnName. This not work for me because i dont have columns with same values on both Tables. I just want to take value from some column in Table2 and add to value in some column in Table1.

When make Update from different columns but same table it work ok. Like this:

`"UPDATE TABLE1 SET TABLE1.Column1=[Table1].[Column1]+[Table1].[Column2] WHERE [Table1].[Column3]=Something;"`

But if i use Table2:

`"UPDATE TABLE1 SET TABLE1.Column1=[Table1].[Column1]+[Table2].[Column1] WHERE [Table2].[Column2]=Something;"`

it give me this error: No value given for one or more required parameters.

I use Visual Basic 2010 and MS Access 2007. Thanks for Help

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I just find solution thanks to MS Access Query Design.

Solution:

```
"UPDATE Table1, Table2 SET Table1.Column1 = [Table1].[Column1]+[Table2].[Column1], Tabel1.Colum2 = [Table1].[Column2]+[Table2].[Column2], Table1.ColumnN = [Table1].[ColumnN]+[Table2].[ColumnN] WHERE (((Table2.[SomeColumn])=SomeValue));"
```

Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Zoran this is not necessarily quite what you were asking for but you can programmatically update values in a table by using visual basic rather than SQL - you pass all the values into a recordset and then update the recordset before committing the changes back to the table. The below example takes the value in a table and alters letter sent value and date sent value. Might be useful for you.
Substitue tablename and column names as appropriate.

```
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

strSQL = "SELECT T008Attendees.PKID, T008Attendees.LetterSentDate, T008Attendees.LetterSent FROM T008Attendees WHERE (((T008Attendees.PKID)=" & ParameterID & "));"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

With rst

If .RecordCount > 0 Then
.MoveFirst
.Edit
!LetterSent = 1
!LetterSentDate = Date
.Update
End If

End With
```

Comment: Hi Dalkeith. I try to finish the job with SQL because is faster than take data from DB do something programmatically  and back this data again to DB. DB will be on other computer in network. Thanks for the answer anyway. It will be help for other situation.